# Unable to install gems with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rbenv

**rbenv**

`$ ruby -v` 
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
`$ gem -v`  
1.8.23

`$ gem install rails`  
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand

`$ gem install railties`  
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand

I spent hours looking for answers...

Also installed `zlib1g-devel` but still cant install rails..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clearly telling you that you don't have zlib:

```
cannot load such file -- zlib
```

You haven't provided any details to what system you are running.

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

or

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel
```

for red hat/centos/ubuntu systems.  You'll then have to ***reinstall ruby***.  You may have some other dependencies and might need libyaml-dev or openssl.

Comment: Thanks. I did install zlib1g-dev but forgot to reinstall ruby. It worked!

Comment: Awesome!  You should mark this as the answer then.  Cheers!